# Linked List School Assignment

Tags: java, linked-list

I am taking a programming class I have the following assignment.

Write a menu driven program that either accepts words and their meanings, or displays the list of words in lexicographical order (i.e. as in a dictionary). When an entry is to be added to the dictionary you must first enter the word as one string, and then enter the meaning as separate string. Another requirement - from time to time words become obsolete. When this happens, such word must be removed from the dictionary.

Use the JOptionPane class to enter the information.

Use the concept of linked list to carryout this exercise. You will need at minimum the following classes:

- A WordMeaning class that hold the name of a word and its meaning.
- A WordMeaningNode class that creates the node of information and its
  link field.
- A WordList class that creates and maintain a linked list of words and
  their meanings.
- A Dictionary class that test your classes.

For the output, the program should produce two scrollable lists:

- The current list of words and their meanings.
- The list of the deleted words. You need not list the meanings, just
  the words.

So far, I have everything coded except for the remove method, and I am not sure how to code that, so could anyone help me please. I coded the add method already, but now I don't know where to begin with the remove method in my WordList class. My classes are below.

WordMeaning Class:

```
public class WordMeaning {

String name;
String definition;

WordMeaning(String t, String d) {
    name = t;
    definition = d;
}

String getName() {
    return name;
}

String getDefinition() {
    return definition;}
}
```

WordMeaningNode Class:

```
public class WordMeaningNode {

WordMeaning wordMeaning;
WordMeaningNode next;

WordMeaningNode(WordMeaning w) {

    wordMeaning = w;
    next = null;
}

public WordMeaning getWordMeaning()
{
    return wordMeaning;
}
}
```

WordList Class:

```
public class WordList {

WordMeaningNode list;

WordList() {
    list = null;
}

void add(WordMeaning w)// In alphabetical order
{
    WordMeaningNode temp = new WordMeaningNode(w);

    if (list == null)
        list = temp;
    else
    {
        WordMeaningNode aux = list;
        WordMeaningNode back = null;
        boolean found = false;

        while(aux != null && !found)
            if( temp.getWordMeaning().getName().compareTo(aux.getWordMeaning().getName()) < 0 )
                found = true;
            else
            {
                back = aux;
                aux = aux.next;
            }

        temp.next = aux;
        if (back == null)
            list = temp;
        else
            back.next = temp;
    }
}

boolean listIsEmpty() {
    boolean empty;
    if (list == null) {
        empty = true;
    } else {
        empty = false;
    }

    return empty;
}

public String toString()
{
    String result = "";
    int count = 0;
    WordMeaningNode current = list;

    while (current != null)
    {
        count++;
        result += current.getWordMeaning().getName() + "\n" + "\t" + current.getWordMeaning().getDefinition();
        current = current.next;
    }

    return result + "\nThe number of words is : " + count;
}
}
```

Dictionary Class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

class Dictionary {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WordMeaning entry;
    WordList diction = new WordList();
    WordList obsolete = new WordList();
    boolean more = true;
    int menuOption = 0;

    String menuMessage = "1. Enter a word and its definition\n2. Remove a"
            + "word\n3. Display all words and meanings\n4. Display"
            + "Removed words\n\n "
            + "Enter the Menu Option (1,2,3, or 4--Any other key"
            + "exits the program)";

    do {
        menuOption = GetData.getInt(menuMessage); //user input

        switch (menuOption) {
            case 1:
                String word = GetData.getString("Enter the word to define:"
                        + " ").toUpperCase();
                String meaning = GetData.getString("Enter the meaning of "
                        + word + " : ");
                meaning = " - " + meaning;
                entry = new WordMeaning(word, meaning);
                diction.add(entry);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word + " was added to"
                        + " the dictionary.", "New Entry",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                break;

            case 2:
                word = GetData.getString("Enter the obsolete word:")
                        .toUpperCase();

                try {
                    diction.remove(word);
                    obsolete.add(new WordMeaning(word, " "));
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word + "has been removed!", "Word Removal", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word + "does not exist", "Word Removal", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                JTextArea text = new JTextArea(diction.toString(), 10, 40);
                JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(text);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pane, "Current"
                        + "Dictionary", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                break;

            case 4:
                text = new JTextArea(obsolete.toString(), 10, 40);
                pane = new JScrollPane(text);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pane, "Obsolete Words",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                break;
            default:
                more = false;

        }
    } while (more);
}
}
```

GetData Class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
class GetData
{
static double getDouble(String s)
{
    return Double.parseDouble(getString(s));
}

static int getInt(String s)
{
    return Integer.parseInt(getString(s));
}

static String getString(String s)
{
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(s);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove a node from a linked list, first search the linked list for that node and then replace all points of reference with a reference to the next node.

Let's call the node we want to remove `current` and the node before that `previous`
(so that `previous.next == current`).
Then just set `previous.next = current.next` and `current` is gone from your list.

A special case is when `current` is the very first node, in which case there is no `previous`.
In that case, set `list = list.next`.

Comment: So I would need to create a search method first?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried to do initially, what would I have to change though?

Answer (score 0):

To remove a node:

- If `diction.list` is the searched object, replace the `diction.list` with `diction.list.next`
- Iterate `current` through the list; if `current.next` is the searched object, set `current.next` to `current.next.next`.

Comment: Yeah, same deal, replace `diction` with `this`.